# How can I query the MSMQ "Message Queuing" security settings?

Tags: powershell, security, acl, msmq

I'm looking to write a PowerShell script to verify the security configuration of MSMQ on some of our servers, e.g. the contents of the Security tab when I run `compmgmt.msc`, then go to `Computer Management (local)` -> `Services and Applications` -> `Message Queueing`, then right-click -> `Properties` -> `Security` tab.

Note that this is not the same as Service Security (which I'm aware I can retrieve via `Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM win32_service' | % PathName | Get-Acl`.

MSMQ apparently has its own unique ACL set and custom permissions which I want to query to ensure that certain Service Principals have the correct permissions as part of a release script.

Does anybody know how to access these custom permissions **ON WINDOWS SERVER 2008** ? I'm also aware that there's an `MSMQ` PowerShell module, but it's only available in 2012 and later versions of Windows Server.